# Can a nuclear reactor also experience freezedowns?

Tags: nuclear-physics

So meltdowns happen when a core gets overheated so much that it becomes very unstable, But is there a way to cool down a reactor so much to the point where it is below freezing and causes a freezedown?

Answer (score 2):

There is one type of reactor in which this would be a problem: a liquid sodium-cooled reactor. These need to be designed so that even when scrammed, the core remains hot enough to maintain the sodium in liquid form. This also requires that the sodium circulation pumps be running at all times so that no part of the loop will solidify. A hard shutdown requires that the liquid sodium be pumped out of the cooling loop and stored in a container that will keep it hot enough to remain in liquid form, because if it freezes solid in the plumbing then restarting the reactor will be very difficult.

Comment: Sounds like a serious accident waiting to happen! ;-)

Comment: @gert, yes, but the bigger problem in practice is preventing leaks, which is nearly impossible to do with 100% effectiveness. a sodium fire in a reactor is a very dangerous thing!

Comment: Tell me about it (I'm a chemist). And don't try putting out the fire with water!

Comment: yeah yeah! big fun.

Comment: BTW, what is the significance of (phi)^2? or is it (psi)?

Comment: $|\Psi|^2$, I'm sure you're familiar with it.

Comment: Ah... the absolute value of the wavefunction squared... probability of finding a particle in a certain location?

Comment: Yes. Of course. The Born principle.